# Output the calculated gamma in ImageMagick -auto-gamme option

Tags: imagemagick, gamma

I need to know the level of gamma correction that ImageMagick is automatically computing when we use the following command

convert in.jpg -auto-gamma out.jpg

Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember correctly, [`-auto-gamma`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-gamma) would call the [`AutoGammaImage`](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/enhance.c#L110) method, and apply the following equation.

```
gamma = log(pixel_mean)/log(0.5)
```

So to calculate what value of gamma correction *will* be applied, you can do something like...

```sh
 pixel_mean=$(identify -format '%[mean]' rose:)
 echo "l($pixel_mean)/l(0.5)" | bc -l
 #=> -14.72189
```

As Mark pointed out in the comments, you can also use [ImageMagick FX language](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php) to calculate.

```sh
identify -format '%[fx:ln(mean*QuantumRange)/ln(0.5)]' rose:
#=> -14.7219
```

Comment: Nice one! Or you can make **ImageMagick** do the maths too... `identify -format '%[fx:ln(mean*65535)/ln(0.5)]' rose:`

Comment: It seams weird having a negative gamme, isn't it just the inverse? 
gamma = log(0.5) / log(pixel_mean)

Comment: I believe negative gamma adjustments are expected. After all, some images will lighten, as others will darken. Checkout [LevelPixel](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/enhance.c#L2369) & [gamma_pow](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/master/MagickCore/enhance.c#L1777) to see how the value would be applied.

Answer (score 2):

-auto-gamma is an experimental option.  For each color channel, it computes the mean of all pixels, then applies

```
  gamma=log(mean)/log(0.5)
```

to each sample.  I've never tried it until just now, but it does work pretty nicely on the severely underexposed photo in this [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77560/improving-the-quality-of-a-picture-taken-at-night/77593#77593).

As far as finding out after the conversion what gamma was applied, that isn't directly reported, but you can use "identify" on the original image and look at the "mean" reported for each channel to figure out the gammas that would be used, as in the answer by emcconville.